# Eclipse is not working in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: java, eclipse, c++

I updated from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10. Eclipse used to work fine in Ubuntu 16.04 but now it is not. The Eclipse for Java (Neon) asks the workspace and after clicking `OK` the error appears:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file /home/Deepak/prog/.metadata/.log
```

And for Eclipse CPP the error message is:

```
 An error has occurred. See the log file /home/Deepak/eclipse/configuration/1483189465157.log.
```

[image: eclipse cpp]

[image: eclipse java-neon]

Comment: "See the log file" and show us what You find, we're not wizards.

Comment: The log file of java-neon contains 461 lines.

Comment: You should go through them,,how do you think you going to detect the real problem?

Comment: Please post the real contents not screen shots of these log files.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an Oracle "Java Early Access" version of JDK 9. I just tried launching Eclipse with this and received the same error as you.

Using the latest Oracle JDK 8 Update 112, it appears to work fine. You can download this [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue after updating to 16.10 -- running on JDK8

Used to have a export that turned off GTK3 in my `eclipse.sh` which had been commented out. Uncommenting that

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

made the toolbars appear again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with UBUNTU 16.10. I solved the issue by installing java 8 version. I followed the instructions from [here](https://www.atlantic.net/community/howto/install-java-jre-jdk-on-ubuntu-16-04/)